# How do I split and join string Java

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I'm using a **RegEx** to match the string fields below so that I get this order:

- Data&HoraUTC
- V
- ProblemaEspecífico
- ID
- DescricaoInformacaoAdicional

I do the first division by removing the blanks, slashes and parentheses. After that, the fields have 1 space between them.

however, I can't separate the fields* V and ProblemaEspecifico* and *ID and Descricao/InformacaoAdditional*.

Can anybody help me. I believe a little adjustment and the code will work.
thank you for your attention and help.

This is the original line.

```
====================================================================================================================                                                                                                                            
Data & Hora (UTC)   V Problema Específico                    ID (Descricao/InformacaoAdicional)                                                                                                                                                             
====================================================================================================================
```

The code :

```
List<String> stringList = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z\\&]{2,}")
            .splitAsStream("Data & Hora UTC, V Problema Específico, ID Descricao/InformacaoAdicional")
            .map(String::trim)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

stringList.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

Result:

```
Data & Hora UTC
V Problema Específico
ID Descricao/InformacaoAdicional
```

Comment: What is the logic behind expected output? I don't see a pattern, i.e in the first part you don't split at space but after the second and third comma you do partially. Why?

Comment: Two questions here : 1) is the input String being generated by your program (or a program under your control)?  If so, a better approach would be to modify that if possible.  2) can you express in English the rules for what constitutes those “fields” - eg is out the first 2 characters after each comma, or the first word after each comma, or …

Comment: I do the first division by removing the blanks, slashes and parentheses.
After that, the fields have 1 space between them.
So my problem is that I need the Data&HoraUTC together as well as the ProblemaEspecífico.

Comment: The input string is being generated by other program. I don't have control.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get a single pattern to do the whole job, so simplest would be to insert the commas yourself for the split to operate on.

So preprocess your string like :

```
List<String> stringList = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z\\&]{2,}")
        .splitAsStream("Data & Hora UTC, V Problema Específico, ID Descricao/InformacaoAdicional"
                .replaceAll(", *([^ ]+))", ", \1,") )
        .map(String::trim)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

That replaceAll changes your String ready for the split, so :

```
"Data & Hora UTC, V, Problema Específico, ID, Descricao/InformacaoAdicional"
```